# How to check age of cached response using Azure API Management and Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: azure, caching, redis, azure-api-management

I'm working with an API in Azure API Management that has an external Azure Cache for Redis instance storing responses. I'd like to see how stale the cached response is via a response header when a cache hit occurs. Although this seems like a basic feature of caches, I can't seem to find any resources or documentation that explains how to achieve this. Ultimately I'd like my frontend to display something to the effect of "your data is 16 minutes old" with an opportunity for the user to sync the latest data (and update the cache in the process).

I tried looking into the attributes available to me through APIM policies but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant there. Worst case scenario I could include a `requestedAt` property in every response from APIM endpoints so that when a cache hit occurs I can see when the original request was made, however I'd rather arrive at this functionality via headers if at all possible.

Edit: Vitaliy's answer below works great. For those curious this is what my policy looks like now

```xml
<outbound>
  <base />
  <set-header name="Cached-At" exists-action="override">
      <value>@(System.DateTime.Now.ToString())</value>
  </set-header>
  <cache-store duration="360" />
</outbound>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect cached response you receive on client side, it may already contain headers like "Date" or "Last-Modified-Since", if those show correct date - use them. Otherwise, if you use `set-header` policy before `cache-store` the value you put in will be stored in cache and returned on retrieval, so this may be used to add cache insertion time to response.

Comment: Worked perfect. There already was a Date header being sent back but it always showed the current time. Adding the header before the `cache-store` did the trick. Thanks Vitaliy!